# Finch Robot with Netbeans Stack Guard Error

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, linux-mint

Recently my school got two Finch robots, one of which they asked me to take home and mess with. I downloaded and opened the Finch project in Netbeans. (I did download the Linux version, as I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela) When I try to connect the finch and run an example program, I get this output

```
Connecting to Finch...this may take a few seconds...
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/joseph/Desktop/NetbeansFinchProject/SourceFiles/libhidapi64.so which might have disabled stack guard. 
The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'
```

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.finchrobot.com/Creating,%20Compiling,%20and%20Running%20Programs%20for%20Finch/netbeans-java), as well as having tried to use execstack -c libhidapi64.so in terminal. I deleted and redownloaded the files, and have spent about 4 hours troubleshooting this. Help?

Note: I'm new to programming, so if the solution seems simple please forgive me lol. Also, ask if you need any more information.

Comment: It looks like a warning. Perhaps you should just ignore it. Are there additional errors/evidence that it is not working?

Comment: I would like to ignore it, but it never finishes connecting. The main additional evidence that it isn't working is that it isn't doing anything.

Comment: It may be that this warning is unrelated to the actual problem. Can you see that the finch is connected with `sudo lsusb`? Perhaps you need to unplug the USB to the finch and reconnect.

Comment: @WillShackleford I tried disconnecting and reconnecting multiple times, whoever I never tried to sudo lsusb. Will try when I get home.